# VS 2103 Cannot Debug asp.net due to Corrupted ScriptResource.axd

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2012, corrupt, scriptresource.axd

I have been working on a very complex asp.net program and suddenly after 2 years of development I receive the following:

I cannot post the Screen Image where but you can see it at: 
http://vmcsys.com/images/VSCorruption.jpg)

This happens in VS2012 Professional while starting a debug session.  The program runs fine outside using any of the major internet browsers.

I have wiped out the entire directory, downloaded a backup.  It seems no matter what I do, I still run into this program.  Where is ScriptResource.axd located?  Should I reinstall VS2012?  I am also using Ajax Toolkit.  Any ideas would very much be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adding the following to Webconfig file

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="false" enableCaching="true"/>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
```